# If a parachain has executed a lease swap, is the DOT in the original crowdloan still returned at the conclusion of the parachain's original lease?

Tags: parachain, crowdloan, lease

If a parachain has executed a lease swap, is the DOT in the original crowdloan still returned at the conclusion of the parachain's original lease, or does it continue to be locked for the duration of the new lease?

I can see there's a function in the `crowdloan` pallet that handles swaps, but I'm not sure how this affects retirement:

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/crowdloan/mod.rs#L840

Pertinent example: Acala's original lease expires in October 2023, but they have successfully executed a lease swap iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lease swap (or anything else) will not impact the crowdloan end date.

Acala have already executed a lease swap, between 2000 (Acala) and 3336.

You can see [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/parachains/crowdloan) the crowdloan is moved to 3336, and will be released with original date (end of lease 13 / Oct 2023).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do I claim my dots back for the first Acala crowdloan? I tried crownloan refund and prachainID 2000 and 3336 but non of them worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/3893)